# Pourquoi on a dit « Où ça ? » au lieu de « Où est ça ? » dans ce contexte ?

Tags: expressions, usage

Je jouais un jeu vidéo en français et l’un des personnages a dit « Où ça ? » et je me demandais pourquoi c’etait cette version courte. C’etait un enfant qui l’a dit donc est-ce que c’est plutôt enfantin cet usage ? Où il y a d’autres expressions avec « ça » comme celle-ci ?

Answer (score 2):

***Où ça ?*** n'est pas un raccourci mais plutôt une version allongée de la question simple ***Où ?*** que le ***ça*** renforce, parfois pour demander de répéter car on n'a pas bien entendu/compris une information qui vient d'être donnée.

Les questions constituées, sur le même modèle, d'un pronom interrogatif suivi de ***ça*** sont courantes dans la langue parlée :

- Où ça ?
- Quand ça ?
- Qui ça ?
- Comment ça ?
- Pourquoi ça ?

Il existe aussi :

- Que ça ?

mais c'est un cas différent car la question *Que ?* n'existe pas.

Les formes suivantes me semblent moins habituelles (régionalismes?), et inusitée pour la dernière.

- Combien ça ?
- Quoi ça ?
- Lequel ça ?

Comment: ah voilà, merci. le contexte était qu’on a parlé d’un pont et le petit a dit « où ça ? » donc ça à bien du sens. ce « Que ça ? » veut dire quoi ? je l’ai jamais vu :))

Comment: *Que ça ?* signifie *Seulement ça ?* - (Is it) only that ? / Is that all ?

Comment: merci beaucoup !